# REST - Linking resource to other resources

Tags: rest

Let's say I have some resources:

```
/users
/companies
```

and in my data model I have a many-to-many relationship between the two entities and the relationship is not symmetrical (like a users can say that he works for a company, but the company may or may not confirm that).

What I would like to do is to model this relationship as a subresource so that

```
/users/:id/companies
```

returns the user companies.

My problem is, what is the proper way to manage the rest interaction between the 2 resources?

**Question 1 - GET :**

If someone GET /users/x I would like to return something like:

```
{
    id: x,
    name: y,
    companies: WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?,
    ...
}
```

I think that I could complete omit the companies field, or that i can just put a link to the real resource

```
{
    id: x,
    name: y,
    companies: {
        href: "/users/x/companies"
    },
    ...
}
```

or maybe

```
{
    id: x,
    name: y,
    companies: [
        href: "/users/x/companies/a",
        href: "/users/x/companies/b"
    ],
    ...
}
```

A different solution would be to return a basic representation of the companies

```
{
    id: x,
    name: yyy,
    companies: [{
        id: a,
        name: zzz
        link: "/user/x/companies/a"
    }],
    ...
}
```

Does this make sense? Maybe it makes sense only when explicitly asked on a request (with something like /users/x?embed=companies)?

Other solutions to manage how the subresources are shown?

**Question 2: POST**

As I wrote the subresource in this case exist as an independent object, so for instance the company entity is already present when it's linked to the user entity.

I can I create this kind of connection?

My idea would be to just model it as:

```
POST /users/:id/companies 
{companyId: a}
```

or even

```
POST /users/:id/companies 
[a, b, c]
```

Which one would you prefer?

Are these strategies too simple or wrong for some reason?

Is there something I may not be considering?

What would be the proper way to create multiple links with the first approach?

Another thing I would like would be to define these links on the user creation. Is it possible to do on a single request?

```
POST /users/ 
{id: x, name: y, companies: [a,b,c]}
```

I think the REST specs say that you should POST a resource by using the same representation you expect on GET. This would be clearly a violation of this principle.

Sorry for the very long question and for any english error.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Kindly add implementation of User and Company classes, like what all member you have in these classes.

Comment: Is it really necessary? I'm trying to keep everything implementation-agnostic and consider only the REST APIs. How the requests are handled by the server should not be relevant here.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. What problems do you have with your last approach of question 1? This looks fine. The user gets basic info about the company and a link he can invoke to learn more about the company - only the link should point here to something like `/company/{id}` IMO as multiple users can work for the same company. Therefore a root resource is fine in this case. Maybe you can follow the HAL style of presenting links: `..., "_links": { "self": {"href": "http://..." }, ... }, ...`

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: I'm not totaly sure on what you meant with `As I wrote the subresource in this case exist as an independent object` - as you declared the company as subresource it is not independend of the user! If you had declared it as peer resource to `/users` it would be independend though referencable from within `/users/{id}`. It is basically up to you how the server handles the linking between users and companies. You can use a bulk `POST` operation, you can use single `POST` operations, you can even use `PUT` or `PATCH` methods if you want

Comment: About q2: what I mean is that in this case the existence and lifecycle of company resource is completely independent of the user resource. I thought it may be a good idea to have URIs like /users/:id/companies/ because I want to clearly signal that companies in that case is just a connection that a user affirms exists. It's this connection that is dependent on the user resource.

Comment: About q1: you are probably right, there is really no need to point to a company as a subresource of user. I thought it was a good idea because maybe there needs to be some symmetry between GET and POST (or whatever) and to create/update a connection between a user and a company you need to refer to a subresource of a user.

Answer (score 0):

I have Employee class like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"displayName"
})

public class Employee {
@JsonProperty("id")
int id;

@JsonProperty("firstName")
String firstName;

@JsonProperty("company")
Company company;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}
public void setCompany(Company comp) {
    this.company = comp;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", company="
            + company + "]";
}
}
```

Company:

```
public class Company {

List<String> company;

public List<String> getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(List<String> company) {
    this.company = company;
}
}
```

POST:

```
@POST
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/json"})
public Employee CreateIt(Employee e) {
    //Implementation
}
```

Body for POST:

> { "company":{"company":["Google","Adobe","Amazon"]}, "firstName":"HeMan","id":101 }

When **company is just a list of names**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Employee {
@JsonProperty("id")
int id;

@JsonProperty("firstName")
String firstName;

@JsonProperty("company")
List<String> company;

public List<String> getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(List<String> company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", company="
            + company + "]";
}
}
```

POST body:

> {"company":["Google","Adobe","Amazon"],"firstName":"Bat Man","id":101}

Comment: Here company is just a list of names, not a real entity. It's not really what I'm looking for.